# Intellij condition is always 'false' when reached is wrong

Tags: intellij-idea

I have the below code. Actually, Throwable t is possible instanceof ServiceException.

```
catch (Throwable t) {
    throwable = t;
    if (t instanceof IllegalArgumentException
            || t instanceof ServiceException) { // here warning Condition 't instanceof ServiceException' is always 'false' when reached 
        throwable = new BizException(t);
    }
    throw t;
}
```

there is a method annotate by @SneakyThrows, is this the reason?

[the warnning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UHaL.png)

Comment: We won't really know without seeing the code before this. However, in my experience IntelliJ has always been right about this particular warning. You did not happen to inherit ServiceException from IllegalArgumentException or anything odd right?

Comment: On another note, it's not recommended catching `Throwable`s because you likely won't be able to recover from `Error`. You're better off catching `Exception`.

Comment: There is a method annotate by @SneakyThrows, is this the reason?

Comment: I made an answer based on that comment

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment:

> There is a method annotate by @SneakyThrows, is this the reason?

Yes that's most likely the reason. I'd remove that unless you have a very specific reason to do that, or cannot change that code. If you can't remove it then it's safe to ignore the warning in IntelliJ.

https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows

Make sure you know when to use `@SneakyThrows` (imho, almost never)